# How to bind Bootstrap Multiselect from database in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing Bootstrap Multiselect control in my AngularJs application. I refer following links

https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Multiselect control works fine for static options but i want to populate same from database. I am unable to find proper way?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#multi-select-demo').multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true
                 });
    });
```

```
<select id="multi-select-demo" class="form-control" multiple
        ng-model="vm.ddlBuilding" ng-options="building as building.name for building in vm.arrBuildings track by building.srNo">
</select>
```

If i comment script tag then all buildings bind to list, but I cant get dropdown multiselect list in that case, simple multiselect list displays on page.

Please suggest how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

We Can use `class` name rather than `id`,it is working fine.

```
<select id="multi-select-demo" class="form-control" multiple name="ddlvessel" multiple="true" class="search-box-open-up" runat="server">


 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.search-box-open-up').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                buttonWidth: 250,
                buttonClass: 'showhide',
                nonSelectedText: 'Select Entities',
                enableFiltering: true

            });
        });
```